# Can I use python 3 functional programming tools from `functools` or `itertools` with `Cython`

Tags: python, functional-programming, cython

I just finished reading Kurt Smith's excellent book on `Cython` but I was left with one question. Can I used functional programming tools from python 3, like `reduce` or `groupby` etc., inside of a `Cython` function?

I was not clear if using these higher level functions would impose additional overhead in `Cython` or if I needed to provide some special type declaration for the functions.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: So that was part of the problem. It seems to work but I can't tell how `Cython` is using these higher level functions when handling the data in the background--whether it is treating it as statically typed for speed-up or dynamically typed.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `cython -a` to get annotated output?

Comment: @Kevin that is a great tip. I am still new to `Cython` so I did not think about that. I will give it a shot.

Comment: You can, but you'll take a performance penalty.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, that is exactly what I was wondering. Is there a more Cythonic way to apply these functional programming tools? I found a package my Matt Rocklin called [pytoolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that might provide some functionality, but I was not sure if I needed to use that. Perhaps I am thinking too much like a python programmer and not enough like a C programmer.

Comment: `cython` gets the most speed improvement when it can produce pure C code without calling python code (even compiled code like `reduce`).  Also it is most useful when replacing python level iteration; or as interface to existing C code.  It's best of find the low level bottlenecks in your Python code, and rewrite just those.

Comment: So I guess I can write answer to this question and just summarize what we have discussed in the comments. Using the higher level functions in Cython does incur a performance penalty, though they will still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon the feedback in the comments section, using higher level functional programming tools, such as `reduce` or `groupby`, etc., will incur a performance loss from `Cython.` While these higher level functions will work within `Cython` modules, the resulting calls back to compiled Python libraries will result in performance loss.